# Set the 'id' attribute using template tags

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Is there a way to set the 'id' attribute in the template?
let's say i pass my `form` as context in my view so when I render some field from my form like `{{form.field1}}` can I set the 'id' something like `{{form.fiel1|attrib=('id':'id_forfieldone')}}`

I know that can be done in the form class definition, but I need to do it in the template.

**EDIT:** Here is the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "manage.py", line 17, in
>         execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)     File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 351,         in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()  File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 343,         in execute
>   self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 177,         in fetch_command commands = get_commands()  File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\lru_cache.py", line 101, 
>         in wrapper result = user_function(*args, **kwds)    File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 72,          in get_commands for app_config in
>   reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 137, 
>         in get_app_configs self.check_apps_ready()  File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, 
>         in check_apps_ready raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded
>   yet.")        django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't
>   loaded yet.

Comment: The id of a form field is `id_fieldname` by default, so in your case it would be `id_field1`.  Why do you need to set it to something else?

Comment: because I add fields dinamically and need to set diferent id for each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/). With help of this you can add classes to your input and edit other attribute also. 
In your case to edit id attribute you can use it like -

```
{% render_field form.fiel1|attr:"id:id_forfieldone" %}
```

Here is good [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/12/04/package-of-the-week-django-widget-tweaks.html) also.

Comment: that is perfect but when i add to 'INSTALLED_APPS' gives me this error 'apps aren't loaded yet'

Comment: post the full trace of your error and what you have added in your settings.py

Comment: I edited the question to show the error tha gives me when I install Widget Tweaks